# Should a listview Adaptor also be responsible for the listview "behaviour"?

Tags: android, listview, design-patterns

I am coding an app where I have a listview containing a textview and a couple of buttons.

In the listview adapter, when I create the view for one listview item, I am also attaching the event handlers to the buttons, whose behavior strictly depend on the value of textview for that listview item.

Now my question is, although it seems the best thing to attach the event handlers to the buttons while creating the view in the adapter, is it a good idea too to have the event handlers themselves in the adapter? I know it will work, but mine is more a concern about separation of code *jurisdiction*. I find it a bit weird that an adapter also contains the code for when the buttons are fired. Do you think that the event handlers could find a better home in the activity containing the listview, rather that in the adapter? What's your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my opinion - yes, you are right, event handlers should be in `Activity`/`Fragment`, containing `ListView`, not in `Adapter`.
Maybe my approach in such case is not ideal, but here it is:
I make an interface in Adapter (or outside it, no matter), for example

```
    public interface MyAdapterCallback {
        void buttonClicked(int buttonId, int position, int param2);
    }
```

Sure, you can pass as many params as you wish.
In `Adapter` constructor I pass instance of object, implementing this interface (`Activity` itself).
Then my `Activity` implements this interface and overrides `buttonClicked()`, where I make desired actions.
And in MyAdapter I put `OnClickListeners` on buttons,
 in `onClick()` I just call `_callback.buttonClicked(passing your params)`.

Hope this answer was useful :)

**Update.**
Ok, I will provide an answer without using interface.
Let your `Activity` implement `OnClickListener` like this:

```
public class MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do your actions here
    }
}
```

Then, here is partially realization of your `Adapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private MainActivity _mainActivity;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, MainActivity mainActivity) {
        super(context, resource);
        _mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button;
        button.setOnClickListener(_mainActivity);
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

In such case, when you press the button - onClick in MainActivity will be called.

**One more option.**
Make your `Activity` like this:

```
public class MainActivity {
    public void onButtonInAdapterClick(your params) {
        //do your actions here
    }
}
```

And an `Adapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private MainActivity _mainActivity;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, MainActivity mainActivity) {
        super(context, resource);
        _mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button button;
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                _mainActivity.onButtonInAdapterClick(your params);
            }
        });
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Choose option you need )

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to C#, so there is a part I didn't get.. you say you pass instance of interface but, interfaces can't have instances?

Comment: I pass an object, implementing this interface (I edited an answer). Yes, interface itself can't have instances. And my code is for Java ;)

Comment: Yeah I thought about that.. :) Well honestly if there is one thing I have to better understand about OOP, is interfaces, that's why I was hesitating to upvote your answer. I don't have the skills to be able to judge it... :\ Maybe if you propose a solution without using interfaces I could be in the position to upvote you :) Thanks a lot for the detail you gave in your answer though, maybe at some time ahead from now I can come back to this and appreciate it fully.

Comment: Pls check my updated answer.